# Angular 2: Disable input field without removing from formgroup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I am working on an Angular 2 project, where I am using forms and validation and have come to the following problem. I have a page with 3 fields:

- height
- weight
- BMI

I would like ALL 3 fields to be in my form so I have done the following:

```
<input name="height" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="height">
<input name="weight" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="weight">
<input name="bmi" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bmi">
```

So far this works fine. Although, I want BMI calculated automatically. I have a function detecting changes on the two fields (height and weight) and calculates the BMI and outputs it in the BMI input field. This works as intended as well.

HOWEVER, I would like to disable the BMI input field in order to prevent the user from being able to type anything. So I have the 3 following criteria:

- The input field here meant to serve as a read only field for the user.
- I also want the BMI to be part of formgroup which I send to my database when all 3 fields are valid.
- (optional, but very much wanted) I want the BMI field to be an input field with the result from height and weight as I have implemented it, not as plain text.

I have tried putting a `[disabled]=true` tag on the BMI input field which doesn't work and gives me a warning that I should add the disabled tag in the formgroup. When I do this or use this command: `this.myForm.controls['BMI'].disable();` it DOES disable it as intended, but also removes it from the formgroup. This means when I submit my formgroup only the value of height and weight is sent, bmi is left out.

How can I do this?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you tried `[readonly]="true"`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing a readonly attribute on the input?

```
<input name="bmi" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bmi" readonly>
```

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar, just saw your comment attached to question. That should work just as well.

Comment: I believe readonly is Html 5, so barring legacy browser issues unless someone else has any thoughts on a legacy-friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of UI framework at all?
http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#read-only-field

Answer (score 0):

formGroup.getRawValue() will return even the disabled fields,

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452175/how-to-make-a-formcontrol-readonly)