# How to make a formControl readonly

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to make a formControl in angular readonly

I know i can do it in html like

```
<input type="text" formControlName="xyz" readonly />
```

how to do it from JS Code and not html i.e in a model driven way

Comment: You can set **disabled** by `this.form.controls.name.disable({onlySelf: true});`, but I didn't find anything for `readonly` so far.

Comment: and here is a relevent issue：
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11447, seems it's not provided right now.

Answer (score 61):

> If you are using Reactive Forms you can assign it dynamically like in
>   the example code below (email field)

```js
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          first_name: ['', Validators.required],
          last_name: ['', Validators.required],
          email: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
          password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
          confirm_password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

If you want to get all the values including disabled controls you should use:

```js
    this.registerForm.getRawValue();
```

> View method comment on source code

```js
    /**
       * The aggregate value of the `FormGroup`, including any disabled controls.
       *
       * If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use this method.
       * Otherwise, the `value` property is the best way to get the value of the group.
       */
      getRawValue(): any;
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: disabling control in formControl leads to null value.

Comment: @PSyLoCKe If you want to get all the values including disabled controls you should use: this.registerForm.getRawValue();

Comment: I don't understand why this was used as the accepted answer... as PSyLoCKe noticed above - getRawValue() will NOT fetch the disabled values. They still come as NULL even if you try getRawValue().

Comment: @tom33pr to avoid confusion please always consult official docs. 
/**
     * The aggregate value of the `FormGroup`, including any disabled controls.
     *
     * If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use this method.
     * Otherwise, the `value` property is the best way to get the value of the group.
     */
getRawValue(): any;

Comment: @PleaseDontBullyMe  If you want to get all the values including disabled controls you should use: this.registerForm.getRawValue();  #stoptobulling haha :)

Comment: Disabling the field does not allow text selection

Comment: getRawValue() does work for me. However this isn't perfect as it would grab all values from all disabled controls.

Answer (score 55):

In my guess there is no use of **READONLY** in a Reactive Form (Angular 2+).

### In a normal HTML, CSS based project

> We use **READONLY** attribute to prevent user from type/select the
> form control but we get value from the input.
>
> We use **DISABLED** attribute to prevent user from type/select the
> form control and we dont get value from the input.

### In an Angular 2+ CLI based Projects

> We don't need **READONLY** attribute to prevent user from type/select.
> Because **DISABLED** attribute is enough to prevent user from type/select and also you
> can get value from the disabled input/select/checkbox/radio field.

You can add disabled attribute to the field in model-driven way

**While creating FormGroup**

```
this.formGroupName = this.fb.group({
    xyz: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
});
```

**At Runtime**

```
this.formGroupName.get('xyz').disable({ onlySelf: true });
```

**Getting values from FormGroup (Edited)**

**To get values from not disabled fields only**

```
this.formGroupName.value;
```

**To get values of all fields in the FormGroup**

```
this.formGroupName.getRawValue();
```

So here you don't need the READONLY attribute.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with disabled fields (in reactive forms) is that they don't pass the validation. The unique way I found was using readonly.

Comment: @Eric There is no use of Validation for Disabled inputs. Brief more about your use of code.

Comment: this did the work, I wanted to disable the input. `disabled: true` did not work in my case but `disable({ onlySelf: true });`

Comment: This makes the field disabled, not readonly.  So CSS styling is not correct.

Comment: @Eric disabled controls pass the validation, but you have to check the validation against "form.control.invalid", instead of "form.control.valid".

Comment: @SilambarasanR its not about validating disabled fields, but about supressing user changes eg for the time of background processing or something - at this point, disabling input to prevent input can result in form.valid potentially switching to true.

Comment: @Antoniossss In that case, you can add a full-screen spinner or you can display a transparent div above the form.

Comment: Nah, I dont have freedom on that. Readonly input however is the solution so there is as rationale to have such mode in reactive forms.

Comment: Ok @Antoniossss I think, you can do like this. After submitting check the form whether it is valid or not then disable the inputs & proceed only if valid. otherwise, you can display errors as you wish. Hope this would help in your case. :)

Comment: There are workardounds, but why not have straight ways? Look how you try to proove that it is not needed by proposing workarounds to this missing bit. Having this way of thoughs I could say that I dont need ReactiveForms at all since I can use ngModel and have [disabled] there right? As an abstract, it would be probably handy to be able to set custom flags/attributes to the FormControl and use them (somehow) in the templates - and be able to set [disable] is just one of them

Answer (score 24):

We can use any html attribute and bind it in angular using `[]`.

So,you can use attribute binding for the attribute `readonly` in that control

e.g

`<input type="text" formControlName="xyz" [readonly]="anyBooleanPropertyFromComponent" />`

Comment: The question is how can add readonly field in model-driven way? Please read question carefully

Comment: I guess, *how to do it from JS Code and not html* is enough.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the answer bt Pankaj got the question right.  How can i do it in a model driven way

Answer (score 4):

For the `reactive-forms`, if you want to make the fields readonly, one way to do so would be to do with plain old javascript using:

```
(document.getElementById('abc') as HTMLInputElement).setAttribute('readonly','true');
```

In addition to this, you can convert the code to more typescript and angular way. Use `@ViewChild` to access the element and then set the `readonly` property to true:

**HTML**

```
<input [formControl]='data' id='abc' #element [readonly]="data.disabled"/>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('element',{static:true, read: ElementRef}) element : ElementRef ;
(this.element.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).readOnly = true;
```

However, you will need to check for the status of the formControl before modifying the readonly property.

Comment: It's show me `Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'select'`

Answer (score 4):

**Manually set formcontrol as `disabled`**

```
control = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true })
```

**Programmatically `enable` / `disable`**

```
<button (click)="enable()">Enable</button>
<button (click)="disable()">Disable</button>

disable() {
   this.control.disable()
}

enable() {
   this.control.enable()
}
```

**Get value from disabled FormControl / FormGroup**

```
this.control.getRawValue() // FormControl
this.form.getRawValue() // FormGroup
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798431/2845996

Answer (score 2):

**A simple solution** is to set the formcontrol as not disabled:

```
this._formBuilder.group({
            some: new FormControl(
              {
                value: parseInt(this.myobject.subObject.stringMember),
                disabled: false
              },
              Validators.required
            ),
```

and, at the same time, to set the `<input>` and/or  `<textarea>` as  readonly:

- textarea:

> ```
>   <label>
>     <span class="label">SomeLabel</span>
>     <textarea
>       maxlength="500"
>       formControlName="some"
>       readonly>
>     </textarea>
>   </label>
> ```

- input:

> ```
> <input type="text" formControlName="name" readonly/>
> ```

this works with input and textarea at least.

Comment: Even if it isn't a best practice, I think this could be used in some situations. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks, @DarioVogogna my answer was first downvoted because I was also showing what could be some bad practices that I now have removed ;-)