# How to set attribute to FormControl programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

**Big question short:** Basically what I want to achieve is, to apply `readonly` attribute to `FormControl` (textbox), right when it's created programmatically.

**Full scenario:**
I have a `Form` that has a `FormRow` whose elements (`FormGroup`s) are partly generated dynamically. I also have given an option to append a row on click of a button.

I want the `FormGroup`'s `FormControl`s (textboxes) that are generated dynamically to be `readonly`, but the manually added `FormControl`s should be editable.

How can I achieve this?

```
<div formArrayName="rows">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of detailForm.get('rows').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="detailSelected[i]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="account" (change)="getAccountAssociatedDetails(detailForm.get(['rows', i, 'account']), 'account', i)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="detailNo" (change)="getAccountAssociatedDetails(detailForm.get(['rows', i, 'detailNo']), 'detail', i)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly formControlName="detailName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly formControlName="detailCountry">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On `change` of textbox value, I'm calling the function `getAccountAssociatedDetails`, as you can see. If there are some details associated with the value entered, I'm replacing that current `FormGroup` and adding some more `FormGroup`s to the row.

```
getAccountAssociatedDetails(control: FormControl, type: string, index: number) {
    let value = control.value;
    if (!!value) {
        let form = this.detailForm;
        control.setErrors({
            'alreadyEntered': null
        });

        if (type === 'detail') {
            if (this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.detailNo.includes(value)) {
                control.setErrors({
                    'alreadyEntered': true
                });
            }
        } else if (type === 'account') {
            if (this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.accountNumber.includes(value)) {
                control.setErrors({
                    'alreadyEntered': true
                });
            }
        }

        // if detail or account is already entered dont call service
        if (!control.hasError('alreadyEntered')) {
            this.agreementDetailsService.getdetails(value, type)
                .subscribe(response => {
                        let associatedDetailsArray = < Array < any >> response;
                        if (!!associatedDetailsArray) {
                            let rows = < FormArray > form.get('rows');

                            // if search mode is 'detail'
                            if (type === 'detail') {
                                if (!this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.detailNo.includes(value)) {
                                    rows.setControl(index, this.builddetailItem(associatedDetailsArray[0].accountNumber.value, value, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailName, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailCountry));
                                    this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.detailNo.push(value);

                                    for (let i = 1; i < associatedDetailsArray.length; i++)
                                        rows.insert(index + i, this.builddetailItem(associatedDetailsArray[i].accountNumber.value, value, associatedDetailsArray[i].detailName, associatedDetailsArray[i].detailCountry));
                                }

                                //if search mode is 'account'
                            } else if (type === 'account') {
                                if (!this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.accountNumber.includes(value)) {
                                    rows.setControl(index, this.builddetailItem(value, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailNo.value, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailName, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailCountry));
                                    this.detailAlreadyEnteredManually.accountNumber.push(value);

                                    for (let i = 1; i < associatedDetailsArray.length; i++)
                                        rows.insert(index + i, this.builddetailItem(value, associatedDetailsArray[i].detailNo.value, associatedDetailsArray[i].detailName, associatedDetailsArray[i].detailCountry));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
}
```

The last two fields in the `FormGroup` are `readonly` by default. Once the user enters something in either of the first two fields and focuses out, the details associated with that value should be fetched, the current `FormGroup` is replaced and other `FormGroup`s in the generated list are appended. I want all the `FormControl`s in those newly added `FormGroup`s should be `readonly`. The user can add more fields and the process repeats.

Comment: Please show us your code, what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: Sure, gimme a minute.

Comment: @AJT_82, included the code.

Comment: @karthikaruna could you please use a minimal sample of code describing your problem. have a look at this please : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe, basically what I want to achieve is, to apply `readonly` attribute to `FormControl` (textbox), right when it's created programatically.

Comment: What if you add `disabled` attribute to the input box? Thats a quick solution

Comment: @PraveenM, I'm OK with that as well.

Comment: @karthikaruna There's also `readonly` for variables as well. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/readonly.html

Comment: @PraveenM, that's not what I'm looking for. Please take a look at the question.

Comment: @karthikaruna Sorry I didn't read the last bit properly. If the generated values are passed from `TS`, why not use oneway data binding? That way any changes wouldn't be written back to the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11447, there isn't a way to add `readonly` on a form control, only `disabled` is supported.

I would even myself prefer `disabled`, since it shows visually (greyed) that user cannot touch it. So when you want to disable your formcontrol, you just use:

```
formControlNameHere.disable();
```

or if you need to disable a whole formgroup, you can do it in the same manner with

```
myFormGroupNameHere.disable()
```

what we need to remember with this, is that this formcontrol is then excluded from the form object. To get all disabled values you need to call:

```
this.myForm.getRawValue();
```

If you do want to add `readonly`, you'd need to do some workaround for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452289/7741865:

```
[readonly]="anyBooleanPropertyFromComponent"
```

Of course in that answer we use a single boolean value, which would of course not work for you, I then see that you'd need to set an additional boolean formcontrol, which you could then bind with the `[readonly]`. But that is just then adding a new "unnecessary" property to your form group, so another reason for just going with `disabled` :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response man, but `rows.setControl(index, this.builddetailItem(value, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailNo.value, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailName, associatedDetailsArray[0].detailCountry).disable());` won't work as `disable()`'s  return type is `void` and doesn't return a disabled `FormGroup`. I'm using `builddetailItem()` to construct and return my `FormGroup`.

Comment: Your code is so complex so it's hard to follow, it would be great if you could for example provide a simplified plunker or stackblitz that showcases the issue you are facing now :)

Comment: Disabled using the `FormArray#at` method in the loop :)

Comment: Great that you figured it out! :)

Comment: But it makes the whole form invalid, making my submit button always stay disabled :( Any workaround!?

Comment: When fields are disabled, they are not included in form object, and should therefore not have anything to do with the validation, as they are technically not part of the form. So I don't know what's going on there, it shouldn't affect the validity. Could you create a demo that showcases this?

Comment: It works if I use `form.invalid` instead of `!form.valid` on the submit button

Comment: Yeah, since not seeing your code for whole form, I could not guess that one. But glad you figured it out! :)