# Pre-populated disabled angular input in a form is considered invalid in template driven

Tags: angular

I have an input field that is disabled and required, the value of this is prepopulated but still, i am getting invalid form control while submission.

```
<input type="text" name="plantCode" id="plantCode" #plantCode="ngModel"
                      [(ngModel)]="runningRecordModel.plantCode" class="form-control" disabled required />
```

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the fields value?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you use disabled then value is marked as null. Which get in conflict with your required condition.

Instead of use disabled, you should use readonly.

1. If you use template driven forms, just use readonly attribute.
2. If you use reactive forms, here are some workarounds for you: [How to make a formControl readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452175/how-to-make-a-formcontrol-readonly)