# Readonly with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I read on [How to make a formControl readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452175/how-to-make-a-formcontrol-readonly) that the best way to obtain a readonly input with Reactive Forms in Angular is to use `specificFormControl.disable()`

That cause me a problem because I want also to use validator of this input, but *.disable()* make my input always as *VALID*

As workaround I use *readonly* in my *.html* file. Unfortunatelly, for calendar and radiobutton input it's not working and force me to use the *disabled* attribute with following warning in console by using reactive forms with *disabled* attribute.

There's a workaround that fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to validate a readonly control? The point of using a validator is to verify what the user entered. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The case is: I have 2 input and if the value of the first is a certain value, the second is compiled with other certain value programmatically and the second one have to become readonly. After that i have to be sure of the validation of the second input

Comment: you can always turn the 2nd field into an textbox instead of disabling it and do a crossfield validation to know if the form is valid. Having the readonly field not showing will not disable the validation and will still be available from the ts file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.